# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Active Directory Samba Doesn't work after reboot

Tags: 18.04, samba, router

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Samba AD Server.  I am using the internal DNS, the isc-dhcp-server for DHCP, wide-dhcpv6-client to get a secondary IPv6 prefix from my ISP and radvd to announce IPv6 addresses to my internal network.  It is currently setup as an IPv4 and IPv6 router with NAT for IPv4.  Everything seems to be working fine, but when I reboot the samba server doesn't fully come back up.  I can do a systemctl restart samba-ad-dc and it starts working again, but it doesn't work right after a reboot.  Just wondering if anyone else has seen this and resolved it?

Answer (score -1):

Look like the service is not enabled to be started at boot? To enable this:

```
systemctl enable samba-ad-dc
```

Of course:

```
systemctl disable samba-ad-dc
```

for the contrary.